# Compass compiling: SCSS partial inside partial

Tags: css, sass, zurb-foundation, compass

First off, I'm all new to SCSS and compiling with Compass but actually love it already!

Everything started when I first downloaded ZURB Foundation (a CSS framework) and tried to edit the styling, so I had to download the additional SCSS files as well. After doing so I had to download a SCSS compiler (in my case KOALA) which did the SCSS to CSS compiling work nicely for me.
I started trying everything out and soon got fed up with every time having to press the compile button when I wanted the SCSS files compiled to a CSS file. So I searched for a solution and found: Compass! I installed Compass and all it's dependencies and it works without any problems.
So when I run Compass (with command: compass watch) it compiles all the SCSS files (main and partial SCSS files) nicely into one CSS file and also updates when editing the main SCSS & also partial ("first level") SCSS file. However, when editing & saving a SCSS partial inside partial ("second level") Compass won't compile the SCSS to CSS! 
This is how my folder structure / scss & css structure looks like:

```
PROJECT
  |
  |---Content
  |      |---css
  |           |---style.css
  |
  |---sass
       |---style.scss (main scss)
       |---_foundation.scss ("first level" partial)
       |---foundation
               |---_functions.scss
               |---components
                       |---_accordion.scss ("second level" partial)
                       |---_alert-boxes.scss ("second level" partial)
                       |---etc... ("second level" partial)
```

(Folder structure has to be contained)

In "style.scss" I import the "first level partial" with the following code:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@import "foundation";
```

In "_foundation.scss" I import several additional partials with the following code:

```
@charset "UTF-8";
@import
  "foundation/components/grid",
  "foundation/components/accordion",
  "foundation/components/alert-boxes",
  "foundation/components/block-grid";
```

And last but not least this is how the "config.rb" file configuration looks like:

```
# Require any additional compass plugins here.
add_import_path "sass/foundation/components"

# Set this to the root of your project when deployed:
http_path = "Views"
css_dir = "Content/css"
sass_dir = "sass"
images_dir = "Content/img"
```

Really hope someone can help me on this as I've been trying to solve this problem for too long now, thanks!

Comment: Do you get an error or does it just not do anything?

Comment: It actually does nothing - i.e. doesn't notice a change of the "second level" partials and hence doesn't compile the SCSS files to a CSS file.

Comment: For Koala, see [issue #137](https://github.com/oklai/koala/issues/137).